# Gift message option x 2

Tags: checkout, customer, free-gift

I'm working on a magento store which, in the checkout, allows customers to provide a gift message for the end consumer. I need to implement this exact functionality again in the same website. So where it once gave an option to give a 'gift message' it will also allow users the option of submitting a 'christmas gift message'.

Once the checkout process is over the customer receives an email with all details including the gift message and an order is created in the backend containing details of the message.

I need to implement the christmas gift message in such a way that it works exactly like the normal gift message but is somehow distinguishable as being specifically a christmas message.

I am unsure about what is the best way to do this. If anyone has done it before it would be a great help to know how you did it or if anyone simply knows of a good way to do this please say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in this I am sharing how  I did this. Feel free to ask any further questions if any aspect of it is not clear.

In the backend where you activate gift messages you have the option to display two types of gift message. One is the normal gift message and the other is an individual product gift message.

I enabled the individual gift message and inside giftmessage/inline.phtml I had to make a few changes. The out of the box solution for individual gift messages displays a form for each product in the checkout as the name would suggest. I basically put a break in the loop after the first form for the first product is displayed. I also made a few edits to the html but after this it was pretty much done.

The Christmas message then shows up on the order sheet in the back end as being related to an individual product but for the store manager this is enough to identify that it is not a normal gift message.

I'm aware this is a bit of a hack but Christmas is not an ongoing event so spending too much time perfecting this seemed unnecessary.